# Legality of graphical representation of "Jell-O"

Tags: copyright, trademark

There are Photoshop tutorials that show you how to create the world "Jell-O" with characters that actually look like Jell-O. However, I believe the word Jell-O is protected by copyright, trademark, or both.

If I write an article about symbols of Utah (which include Jell-O) and illustrate it with a Photoshopped "Jell-O," would that be legal?

Actually, the article would be a chapter in a commercially sold book published in the U.S.

Comment: Wow, that answers several questions I've been researching.